# How to update a set of records based on two different field values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a really difficult time conceiving how to do the following. Basically I have a table such as the following with a two key fields (an id field and another field with a numerical identifier...

```
ID      fldNumData   fldData
49562   1            1.145816 
49562   2            2.165815
49562   1            5.15165
49562   1            6.156156
32564   2            ...
48151   2            ...  
54919   2            ...
54919   3            ...
```

I need to insert a record into another table for each set of records based on the ID and fldNumData, such as gettings the avg of fldData where the ID = 49562 and the fldNumData = 1, but I need to do this for set of keys and NumData. How can I create a query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, what you want is:

Assuming that secondTable has the fields ID, fldNumData and fldDtaAverage you do:

```
INSERT INTO secondTable
SELECT ID,fldNumData,AVG(fldData)
FROM thisTable
GROUP BY ID,fldNumData
```

Answer (score 0):

try following query. its easy to answer if you mention what are the column names of your 2nd table

```
INSERT INTO TABLE table_2 VALUES(SELECT AVG(fldData) FROM table_1 WHERE id='49562' AND fldNumData='1');
```